# How do I hide the new Chrome v84.0.4147.89 Issues Detected messages in the Console area?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, panel, inspect

Since latest Chrome update, version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)) on 14 July 20, when I open the brower's Inspection (debugging) panel, I see '`Issues detected: The new Issues tab displays information about deprecations, breaking changes and other potential problems.`' and can't see the first (few) messages in the console area until click the 'Go To Issues' button.

Putting 'cross-site references' in the Console filter does hide the messages that contain these words, but it doesn't prevent the Issues detected message and the need to click the button to clear it.  There isn't a similar filter in the new Issues tab.

How do I hide or prevent this message and the need to click this button?

Note, I want the issues to show in the Issues tab, but I don't want to have to look at them to clear Chrome's new message.

This message and the Issues messages show on the Google home-search page, other web-pages, and the web-site that I'm developing.  So since the Google home-search page and other web-pages shows the same messages, the problem isn't specific to my site. However, I'm concerned that Chrome is going to block Cross-Site cookies that I have no control over in the near future, and that this will effect my site.

Just in case the Issues messages are important to finding a solution, here is what I see in the new Issues tab when I click the button:

```
21 Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute

2 Indicate whether a cookie is intended to be set in cross-site context by specifying its SameSite attribute
```

When I look at the details of the above messages by opening them, I see that none of these relate to my site, so I don't have control over how these sites/resources make their content available.  Here are the message details:

```
Because a cookie's SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to
SameSite=Lax, which will prevent the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request
in a future version of the browser. This behavior protects user data from
accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.

Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie: Specify SameSite=None
and Secure if the cookie should be sent in cross-site requests. This enables third-
party use. Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be sent
in cross-site requests

12 cookies
Name      Domain & Path
_ga       .stripe.com/
ANID      .google.com/
OGPC      .google.com/
OGP       .google.com/
SID       .google.com/
HSID      .google.com/
SSID      .google.com/
APISID    .google.com/
SAPISID   .google.com/
DV        www.google.com/
SIDCC     .google.com/
PREF      .youtube.com/

11 requests
v2/
v3/
api.js?hl=en
 : I edited these out
log ...
```

The second message says:

```
Because a cookie's SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to
SameSite=Lax, which will prevents the cookie from being set in a cross-site context
in a future version of the browser. This behavior protects user data from
accidentally leaking to third parties and cross-site request forgery.

Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie: Specify SameSite=None
and Secure if the cookie is intended to be set in cross-site contexts. Note that
only cookies sent over HTTPS may use the Secure attribute. Specify SameSite=Strict
or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be set by cross-site requests

2 cookies
Name        Domain & Path
SIDCC       .google.com/
remote_sid  .youtube.com/

1 request
api.js?hl=en
```

** Update **
Still no resolution to this issue, but I thought I'd add that the console used to display coding errors, such as in my javascript functions, no longer appears to do that.  Now, when I have a syntax error in one of my functions, I don't see any console messages and really only find that there is a problem when I try to call a non-existing function.  Then I have to locate the function's definition and visually scanning the 'missing' function it for the line that has a red-x after it.  Chrome used to do this for me, but now I have to do this.  I believe that this may be related to the new cross-site issue alert getting in the way or my attempt to filter out these alerts, which is only partly successful.

CHROME -- This isn't an improvement.

Also, unless the resource is part of my site, what do you expect me to do about this, if anything?  Not use them?  I guess you think you know best and will soon just block me from getting to them.  THAT'LL BE GREAT, I CAN'T WAIT FOR THAT TO HAPPEN.  Your lack of details on how to best handle all of this will send the internet back to the dark-ages where we could only show text, no videos and no pictures that aren't hosted in the same site so long as we continue to use Chrome!  Let's see IE and Edge shot themselves in the head, now Chrome, I guess it's time to switch to FireFox.  Are you listening Chrome?

Thank you